# Is email authentication using id token possible?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm creating a POC for an iOS application that uses extension. The extension has to know if a user is authenticated. Unfortunately a containing app and an extension are separate application which means I have to keep auth state somewhere.

I don't want to store user email and password but instead a token and use it to authenticate. However trying to authenticate with the issued **token** and **providerId** (**Firebase**) does seems to work.

Both apps under the same Firebase project.

Main Application **(Firebase ios App1)**:

```
let userDefatuls = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.test")
userDefatuls?.set(providerId!, forKey: "providerId")
userDefatuls?.set(value!, forKey: "token")
print("Saved value to user defaults \(value!)")
userDefatuls?.synchronize()
```

Extension Application **(Firebase ios App2)**:

```
let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.test")
let token = userDefaults?.string(forKey: "token")
let providerId = userDefaults?.string(forKey: "providerId")
print("What is the provider id \(providerId)")
let credential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: providerId!, accessToken: token!)
Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
    print("********* What is the user \(user) what is the error \(error)")
}
```

The above renders:

What is the user nil what is the error:

> Optional(Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={error_name=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information., NSUnderlyingError=0x600000447290 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={
>       code = 400;
>       errors =     (
>                   {
>               domain = global;
>               message = "INVALID_PROVIDER_ID : Provider Id is not supported.";
>               reason = invalid;
>           }
>       );
>       message = "INVALID_PROVIDER_ID : Provider Id is not supported.";
>       }}}})

Do you know if the support and works? Is there something what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't sign in with a Firebase ID token. What you can do is:
Create an endpoint that takes an ID token, verifies it:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

and returns a custom token:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

You then signInWithCustomToken in the extension.

However, this could open a vulnerability as if a short lived ID token is leaked, the attacker can exchange it for a permanent session via that endpoint.

You can only return the custom token if the `auth_time` on the ID token is recent. This ensure that a recently signed in user can sync their app to with the extension.